# CAT5/6 to non RJ45 connector assemblies

Tags: connector, ethernet, interconnect

What types of non-RJ45 cable assemblies plugs/sockets are common? I need to carry instrumentation signals (8 of them) which are a mix of small signal and 60Vpp. I cannot use RJ45 in case someone thinks its Ethernet and destroys their PC by connecting to it

Comment: DB9 is a common one for custom data signals.

Comment: How about the 10-pin version of RJ45? It won't fit into an ethernet port...

Comment: A possibility, but I expect the box will have one of those for RS232 comms. I would also like some company that already makes such cable assemblies to cut down on the cost of custom. I'm beginning to think my requirements are impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your design, you can try the following:

- 2-mm (preferably) or 2.54-mm (possible) pitch [IDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector) connection, initially designed for flat ribbon cable but works with stranded CAT5 UTP well.
- BNC connection, especially as you noted about instrumentation (measurements?), here soldering is needed.  In that case you can also use RCA and similar ones.
- so called "euroconnection", 3.51-mm (or wider if needed), where you can connect both stranded and/or solid UTP.

  [image]

Maybe it looks like a hack, i.e. non-standard, but as you mentioned your approach is initially not standard too. All these connection are popular (and therefore cheap) and pluggable many times.